# How to get the date of the beginning of the month in SSIS Script Task?

Tags: sql, ssis, bids

I'm using SSIS and I have a script task that I want to change the value of a variable if today's date is the beginning of the month.

So I would like to change the value of the boolean variable `startDate` to TRUE if it's the beginning of the month when the task runs and FALSE otherwise.

Essentially I'm missing the SSIS Script version of this SQL statement:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @mydate), 0) AS StartOfMonth
```

Here is my script so far:

```
        public void Main()
    {
        if (DateTime.Today = ?  )
        {
            Dts.Variables["User::startDate"].Value = True;
        }
            Dts.Variables["User::startDate"].Value = False;

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
}
```

**ANSWER:**

```
    public void Main()
{

DateTime value = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year,DateTime.Today.Month,1);

if (DateTime.Today == value )
{
    Dts.Variables["User::startDate"].Value = bool.Parse("True");
}
    Dts.Variables["User::startDate"].Value = bool.Parse("False");

Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use :

```
public void Main()
{

  DateTime value = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year,DateTime.Today.Month,1);

    if (DateTime.Today == value )
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::startDate"].Value = bool.Parse("True");
    }
        Dts.Variables["User::startDate"].Value = bool.Parse("False");

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm getting an error with the data type of the variable being a boolean but the value being passed in being a string. Removing the quotation marks didn't solve this.

Comment: Try to pass it as a bit 0 or 1

Comment: Remember that the variable name is case sensitive

Comment: I tried both of those methods and got this error: The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::startDate" differs from the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution

Comment: Try (bool)"True"  or (bool)1

Comment: I got it to work by using bool.Parse("True") and bool.Parse("False")